# ¿Cómo ejecutar un método dependiendo de la entrada del teclado en Python?

Tags: python

estoy realizando este ejercicio en el cual un usuario **va a ingresar un número del 1 al 4 para ejecutar un método** que está en el diccionario del método main(), el problema está en que cuando ingreso un número diferente de 1, **se sigue ejecutando el método 1 que esta en el diccionario**, y el objetivo es que que si presiono el 2, 3 ó 4 no me pida los datos que pide el método 1.
No se si me dí a explicar, pero... este es mi código de Python:

```
import re, sys, json


class Crud:
    def __init__(self, option):
        self.option = option

    def main(self):
        while not self.option or not re.match(r'[sS1-4]+$', self.option) or len(self.option) > 1:
            self.option = input("    Teclea una opción dentro de los corchetes y Presiona [Enter]: ")

        if self.option == "S" or self.option == "s":
                print("\n    !!!app cerrada!!!".upper())
                sys.exit()

        else:
            self.option = int(self.option)
            dict = {
                1: self.create(),
                2: self.read(),
                3: self.update(),
                4: self.delete(),
            }
            for k, v in dict.items():
                if self.option == k and dict[self.option] == v:
                    return dict[self.option]

    def create(self):
        nombre = input(f"    Ingresa tu Nombre(s): ")
        a_paterno = input(f"    Ingresa tu Apellido Paterno: ")
        a_materno = input(f"    Ingresa tu Apellido Materno: ")
        nacimiento = input(f"    Ingresa tu Fecha de Nacimiento (dd/mm/aa): ")
        edad = int(input(f"    Ingresa tu edad: "))
        sexo = input(f"    Ingresa tu sexo (Masculino ó Femenino): ")

        imprimir = {
            "sort_keys": False,
            "indent": 4,
            "ensure_ascii": False,
            "default": str,
        }

        dict_datos = {
            "first_name": nombre,
            "last_name": a_paterno + " " + a_materno,
            "birthday": nacimiento,
            "edad": edad,
            "sexo": sexo,
        }

        return f"    Estos son tus Datos:\n{json.dumps(dict_datos, **imprimir)}"
        # return f"    Este es el método para Crear un datos"

    def read(self):
        return f"    Este es el método para Leer datos"

    def update(self):
        return f"    Este es el método para Actualizar un dato"

    def delete(self):
        return f"    Este es el método para Eliminar un dato"


opcion = str(input(f"    Dame un número: "))
objeto = Crud(opcion)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"{objeto.main()}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es que al asignar tus métodos en el diccionario estas utilizando los paréntesis `()`, eso le indica al programa que estas ejecutando la función. Para asignar el método a un valor del diccionario debes asignarlo al nombre de la función pero sin paréntesis, por ejemplo:

```
1: self.create
```

Otro problema es que la palabra `dict` es reservada (Se usa para crear diccionarios), debes renombrar esa variable, por ejemplo a `d`

Para poder ejecutar la función que deseas en la comparación del `for` agregas los paréntesis al final, de la siguiente forma:

```
return d[self.option]()
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import re, sys, json


class Crud:
    def __init__(self, option):
        self.option = option

    def main(self):
        while not self.option or not re.match(r'[sS1-4]+$', self.option) or len(self.option) > 1:
            self.option = input("    Teclea una opción dentro de los corchetes y Presiona [Enter]: ")

        if self.option == "S" or self.option == "s":
                print("\n    !!!app cerrada!!!".upper())
                sys.exit()

        else:
            self.option = int(self.option)
            d = {
                1: self.create,
                2: self.read,
                3: self.update,
                4: self.delete,
            }
            for k, v in d.items():
                if self.option == k and d[self.option] == v:
                    return d[self.option]()

    def create(self):
        nombre = input(f"    Ingresa tu Nombre(s): ")
        a_paterno = input(f"    Ingresa tu Apellido Paterno: ")
        a_materno = input(f"    Ingresa tu Apellido Materno: ")
        nacimiento = input(f"    Ingresa tu Fecha de Nacimiento (dd/mm/aa): ")
        edad = int(input(f"    Ingresa tu edad: "))
        sexo = input(f"    Ingresa tu sexo (Masculino ó Femenino): ")

        imprimir = {
            "sort_keys": False,
            "indent": 4,
            "ensure_ascii": False,
            "default": str,
        }

        dict_datos = {
            "first_name": nombre,
            "last_name": a_paterno + " " + a_materno,
            "birthday": nacimiento,
            "edad": edad,
            "sexo": sexo,
        }

        return f"    Estos son tus Datos:\n{json.dumps(dict_datos, **imprimir)}"
        # return f"    Este es el método para Crear un datos"

    def read(self):
        return f"    Este es el método para Leer datos"

    def update(self):
        return f"    Este es el método para Actualizar un dato"

    def delete(self):
        return f"    Este es el método para Eliminar un dato"


opcion = str(input(f"    Dame un número: "))
objeto = Crud(opcion)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"{objeto.main()}")
```

Comment: Incluso, creo que se puede omitir el bucle for, y solo dejar: return d[self.option]()

Comment: Así es, pero intenté no modificar el código y únicamente abordar los problemas que tenía

Comment: @GabrielAbraham, Si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas